# Multi file php upload

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I'm trying to upload multi images to server and store their names into the mysql db. I can't figure why the script is appending 0, 1, 2... at the beginning of each image name. And why renaming doesn't work, if I upload a image with the same name it replaces is.

```
$images = array();
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
  foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
      $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        } 
        $desired_dir="images";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);    // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
            }else{                  //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="images/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;       
            }
            $images[] = $file_name;     
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
  if(empty($error)){
    $imglinks = implode(" | ", $images);
  }
  echo $imglinks;
}
```

Comment: This line cause `$file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];` appending 0, 1, 2... at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

$key was concatenated to the filename

```
$images = array();
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
  foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
      $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        } 
        $desired_dir="images";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);    // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
            }else{                  //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="images/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;       
            }
            $images[] = $file_name;     
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
  if(empty($error)){
    $imglinks = implode(" | ", $images);
  }
  echo $imglinks;
}
```